# how to use multiple videos with background in it with color correction

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php, pyffmpeg

Hey i am try to create a batch input output file with that so i can easliy add my video in to a frame with top header and footer GIF for youtube subscribe and credit in the right side my logo and card should be display and the left the actual video should be shared to avoid video theifs please help me out

look at my code but not working
`for %%a in ("_input\*.*") do ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i "%%a"  -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1; movie=111.mp4" -codec:a copy -movflags +faststart _output\%%~na.mp4`

look at the image what i acutaly want any kind of help would be much much appreciated thank you[[image]]

Comment: why try to do this with ffmpeg when there are programs for video editing

Comment: i need to use this for bulk files and video editors take 30 mintues to export the file of 1 hour duration while ffmpeg does that under 10 minutes

Comment: is time really a constraint? a video editor can work while unattended, for example in the night; if we're talking about hundreds or thousands of videos i could see that it makes a difference, but only that